# SSH connection between two Pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to do ssh between two pods in kubernetes.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: In general you would not, since `docker` is not a virtual machine, but rather ideally the compartmentalization of a single binary and its dependencies. What do you hope to do if you had a working ssh connection?

Comment: Separate from that, every Pod (unless it was explicitly disabled) has credentials to interact with the Kubernetes API, and thus could invoke commands in the neighboring docker container in the same way `kubectl exec` does -- would that accomplish your goal?

Comment: last statement is not exactly true with RBAC enabled

Answer (score 1):

Oversimplifying the answer, you can not.

That is, under "normal" circumstances... Your containers in pod launch single process, that is your application, be it nodejs, php, java or whatever, so they do not have a running SSH server inside their namespaces. Unless you explicitly run it by ie. running a "fat" container that launches a supervisor process (like ie. by using something like `phusion/baseimage` container) which by most in container world is considered an anti-pattern, or by running ssh in sidecar container, which will allow you to access that ssh server (but it will have it's own FS and potentially process tree, unless shared PID namespace is used).

As suggested in another answer, you could use serviceaccounts to grant your software rights to call kubernetes API and hence use things like ie. `kubectl exec`. Is it the right call for you... that depends on what you really want to achieve in the end.

Comment: I have 1 application running on 1 pod and other application on other pod. I need to do ssh from one pod to other pod and access file system